# How to read a file in current directory through Java Class in another directory

Tags: java, xslt

I am working on Linux OS.

I am facing trouble parsing & transforming the XML file though Java.

Location of Java XMLTransform.class: /home/apps/source (this path is present in CLASSPATH)
Location of XML file (working directory): /home/apps/nk/working/payload.xml

When I am inside the "Working Directory", I am invoking XMLTransform.class passing XML filename payload.xml to it but getting following error:

```
XML-22004: (Fatal Error) Error while parsing input XML document (Invalid InputSource.).
---------
oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException: Invalid InputSource.
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors1(XMLError.java:320)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.pushXMLReader(XMLReader.java:248)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:202)
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.transform(JXTransformer.java:321)
    at TransformationEngine.main(TransformationEngine.java:30)
```

It is clear that class is not able to resolve the file name.

Please give pointers as to how I can resolve this?

Note: invoice_transformer.xsl is placed in same directory as .class file and CLASS file is able to read it.

Java Code:

```
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TransformationEngine {
public static void main(String[] args){

    String payloadFileName = args[0];

    String xslFile = "invoice_transformer.xsl";

    InputStream is = java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(xslFile);
    InputStream pfis = java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(payloadFileName);

    try{
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(is));
        transformer.transform(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(pfis),new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("IDMpayload.csv")));

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have to use `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream`? It looks like [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) would work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSystemResourceAsStream()` looks for the resource in the CLASSPATH.  You don't have `/home/apps/nk/working/` in your CLASSPATH (do you?).

Instead use FileInputStream (as suggested by @Banthar )